# Installing "ffmpeg" package from setup.py in Apache Beam pipeline running on Google Cloud Dataflow

Tags: python, ffmpeg, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, setup.py

I'm trying to run an Apache Beam pipeline on Google Cloud Dataflow that utilizes FFmpeg to perform transcoding operations. As I understand it, since ffmpeg is not a python package (available through PIP), I need to install it from setup.py using the following lines

```
# The output of custom commands (including failures) will be logged in the
# worker-startup log.
CUSTOM_COMMANDS = [
    ['apt-get', 'update'],
    ['apt-get', 'install', '-y', 'ffmpeg']]
```

Unfortunately, this is not working. My pipeline is stalling and when I go to examine the logs I'm seeing this

[image]

```
RuntimeError: Command ['apt-get', 'install', '-y', 'ffmpeg'] failed: exit code: 100
```

It appears to be unable to find the package 'ffmpeg'. I'm curious as to why this is - ffmpeg is a standard package that should be available under apt-get.

Comment: This is possibly due to ffmpeg conflicting with a package already installed in Dataflow workers. Can you contact Google Cloud Support (https://cloud.google.com/support/) with a job ID ?

Answer (score 1):

I had forgotten to properly run `apt-get update` before attempting the install. Make sure to run that before trying to install any packages.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install ffmpeg on Dataflow using Beam 2.12.0 and back to 2.3.0. I saw this error on 2.2.0 and older. I also saw this issue without 'apt-get update' first, so make sure that didn't fail.

Comment: this was an issue of `apt-get update` -- my fault. Thanks!